# How to use two registers in Vim substitute :s

Tags: vim

If I have two registers have content on it
e.g.

```
"a=<span>
"b=</span>
```

I want to substitute command like that:

```
 %s/pattern/"a \0 "b/gc
```

I'm wondering it is possible in Vim?
BTW, I don't want to paste the content of registers into

```
%s/pattern/"a \0 "b/gc
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `\=` to declare a `sub-replace-expression` and use `@a` to access the content of register `a` (the `.` indicate string concatenation):

```
:s/pattern/\=@a.submatch(0).@b/
```

Comment: thanks! BTW, why   :s/pattern/\=@a . \0 . @b/gc does't work?

Comment: @elliptic00: when using `\=` vim evaluates the replace part. `\0` is not a valid vim function (it's a regex back reference), so you have to use `submatch()`.